# DB2 Import with modified timestamp format for time with EDT/EST attached to it

Tags: sql, database, db2, bulk-load

I have a file `import_file.csv` with the below mentioned timestamp format.

```
Oct/21/2013 09:45:01 AM EDT
Dec/04/2013 04:41:01 PM EST
```

I created a table in IBM DB2 v9.7

`create table table_import_timestamp ( my_timestamp timestamp )`

And then tried importing the file.

```
db2 import from import_file.csv of del messages msg.out insert into table_import_timestamp
```

I did try with a few modified timestamp format available in db2 import utility but didn't find one that is suitable to import the timestamp with the format mentioned in the file.

Is there a way for me to import this format in to a table without modifying the file and by specifying the timestamp format in my import statement itself?

Comment: You could use the `timestampformat` modifier, if it weren't for the time zone specifications in your file. DB2 timestamps do not carry the time zone information, so your data cannot be imported as they are.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So if I cannot import the data from the file as they are, will I at least be able to ignore the timezone in the file within my import statement. I do not want to modify the file that I receive from elsewhere. Just need to load the data what is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to lose time zone information, you have a couple of options.

1.Use the `INGEST` command, which allows you to manipulate input data before inserting:

```
ingest from file YOURFILE format delimited ($ts char) restart off
  insert into YOURTABLE (TS_COLUMN) 
  values (
   timestamp_format(left(cast($ts as varchar(30)),23),'Mon/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  )
```

You can even add an extra column to your table to store the time zone offset value, e.g.

```
ingest from file YOURFILE format delimited ($ts char) restart off
  insert into YOURTABLE (TS_COLUMN,TZ_COLUMN) 
  values (
   timestamp_format(left(cast($ts as varchar(30)),23),'Mon/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),
   case when right(cast($ts as varchar(30)),3) = 'EDT' then -4 else -5 end
  )
```

You will need to install version 10.1 of the DB2 client for that, as `INGEST` was not available in the 9.7 client. It will still work with the 9.7 server.

2.Relax your "don't want to modify the file" requirement and use something like `sed` or `perl` to reformat the data on the fly, e.g.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
db2 "import from /tmp/mypipe of del 
modified by timestampformat=\"MMM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT\" 
insert into YOURTABLE (TS_COLUMN)" &
perl -npe 's/ E(D|S)T(,|$)//' YOURFILE > /tmp/mypipe
rm -f /tmp/mypipe
```

By using the OS pipe you don't modify the original file and don't use extra disk space either.